# Gitlab CI: Is it possible to speed up 'bundle install'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I use gitlab.com and CI with the shared docker runner that runs tests for my Ruby on Rails project on every commit to master. I noticed that about 90% of the build time is spent on 'bundle install'. Is it possible to somehow cache the installed gems between commits to speed up the 'bundle install'?

**UPDATE:**

To be more specific, below is the content of my .gitlab-ci.yml. The first 3 lines of the 'test' script take about 90% of the time making the build run for 4-5 minutes.

```
image: ruby:2.2.4

services:
  - postgres

test:
  script:
    - apt-get update -qy
    - apt-get install -y nodejs
    - bundle install --path /cache
    - bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test
    - bundle exec rspec
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you have special requirements for doing a apt-get all the time, if that is not needed create your own dockerfile with those commands in it. So that your base has already those updates/nodejs packages. If you want to update later on, you can always update your dockerfile again.

For your gems, if you want it quicker you can cache them in between builds too. Normally this is per job and per branch. See example here http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#cache

```
cache:
  paths:
  - /cache
```

I prefer to add `key: "$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME"` so that for that particular branch my files are cached. See [environments](http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html) to see what keys you can use more.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup `BUNDLE_PATH` environment variable and point it to a folder where you want your gems to be installed. The first time you run `bundle install` it will install all gems and consequent runs will only check if there are any new gems and install only those.

Note: That's supposed to be the default behavior. Check your `BUNDLE_PATH` env var value. Is it being changed to a temporary per commit folder or something? Or, is *90% of the build time* being spent on downloading gem meta information from rubygems.org? In which case you might want to consider using `--local` flag (but not sure this is a good idea on CI server).

```
Fetching source index for https://rubygems.org/
```

---

<strike>After looking at your `.gitlab-ci.yml` I noticed that your `--path` options is missing `=`. I think it is supposed to be:</strike>

```
      - bundle install --path=/cache
```

Comment: does your answer still apply to the standard CI runner hosted by gitlab.com?

Comment: Yeap. I noticed another potential reason. Updated my answer.

Comment: I believe '=' is not required per documentation here: http://bundler.io/v1.3/bundle_install.html

Comment: Is it possible that gitlab is running a fresh docker image on each build, so setting --path doesn't make a difference, because next time it will be a completely new image (maybe even running on a different physical machine)?

Comment: "*'=' is not required*" - looks like it. I looked at `man` files and assumed they were required. As for your second question, yeap, that would be quite logical.